# How iota prevents data tampering /data immutability?

Tags: iota

How does iota (tangle) prevent data tampering issues since it relies on directed acyclic graph and do not follow any linear pattern . In blockchain we have blockhash which is appended to next block and so on which makes it hard for an attacker to tamper data . How iota prevent such attacks ?

Answer (score 1):

In the same way as a block in a blockchain cannot be modified without invalidating all the subsequent blocks in the chain, a transaction in the IOTA tangle cannot be modified without invalidating all the transactions that *approve* (directly or indirectly) that transaction. In the visual representation of the tangle as a directed acyclic graph, when a transaction A approves a transaction B there is an edge going from vertex A to vertex B.

The process of approving a transaction is conceptually similar to that of attaching a new block to the end of a blockchain: in both cases there is a cryptographic
puzzle to be solved. For the IOTA tangle, a node that wants to approve a transaction needs to find a nonce such that the hash of that nonce concatenated with some data from the approved transaction has a particular form.

Thus, data immutability is guaranteed in the tangle by issuing new transactions that "lock" previous transactions, in the same way as a block attached to a blockchain "locks" the blocks already present in the chain.